# Default template function argument

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

With reference to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

template < bool bitwise = false, typename T>
// template <typename T,  bool bitwise = false>  
// ^ wont work! error: no matching function for call to 'func<true>(int, int)'

bool func(T a, T b) {
    if constexpr(bitwise) {
        return a & b;
    }
    else {
        return a && b;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << func(7,1) << endl;
    cout << func<true>(7,1) << endl;
}
```

Why do I have to specify the argument `bitwise` first in the `template` list ? Compiler can deduce T from the function arg so why does `bitwise` need to be the first one in this case?

Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xtB2jhmNfBh7IoJz

Answer (score 4):

It's because of this call:

```
cout << func<true>(7,1) << endl;
```

This instantiates the template with `true` as its first (and only) template parameter.

When instantiating a template, any explicit template parameters get assigned ***to the initial parameters in the template declaration*** and any ***remaining*** parameters must be deducible. This pretty much leaves the given order of template parameters (in the template declaration) as the only order that will work.

Comment: Thanks! But why ? is this just a rule? I understand what is happening but WHY is this happening? sorry if thats too much to ask for over a comment

Comment: Because that's how C++ works is pretty much the short answer. When only some template parameters are specified there must be some clear and unambiguous set of rules that determines which template parameters get explicitly specified and which ones must get deduced. The compiler is not going to try every possible combination until it finds one that works. Therefore the rule is: explicit template parameters given when instantiating a template go with the initial parameters in the template's declaration, and the rest must end up getting deduced.

Comment: I guess a better question to ask should be why does the language let the user override the `template` type that has to be deduced (`static_cast` should be enough if user really needs it). I guess i could use auto to force deduction but that doesnt work pre-C++11. Maybe I should think about in which cases will ignoring types in `<>` the deduced types break existing code/patterns